Hibernate Convert String Values to Varbinary and try insert as Hexa decimal
I have following model class that
@ToString
@Entity
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "fare_rules")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FareRule implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "rule_key")
    private long ruleKey;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;//

    @Column(name = "basis_code")
    private String basisCode;//

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;//

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;//

    @Column(name = "min_pax_count")
    private int minPaxCount;

    @Column(name = "pax_category_id")
    private long paxCategoryID;

    @Column(name = "currency_id")
    private String currencyID;//

    @Column(name = "booking_time")
    private String bookingTime;//

    @Column(name = "exclude_from_stopovers")
    private boolean excludeFromStopovers;

    @Column(name = "allowed_adult")
    private boolean allowedAdult;

    @Column(name = "allowed_child")
    private boolean allowedChild;

    @Column(name = "allowed_infant")
    private boolean allowedInfant;

    @Column(name = "enable_validity_period")
    private boolean enableValidityPeriod;

    @Column(name = "segment_name")
    private String segmentName;//

    @Column(name = "allowed_adult_refund")
    private boolean allowAdultRefund;

    @Column(name = "allowed_child_refund")
    private boolean allowChildRefund;

    @Column(name = "allowed_infant_refund")
    private boolean allowInfantRefund;

    @Transient
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fare_rule_id", updatable = false)
    private FareRuleDetails details;

    @Transient
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fare_rule_id", updatable = false)
    private FareRuleJourneys journeys;

    @Builder.Default
    @Volatile
    @Column(name = "version")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String version = "1.0";//

    @Volatile
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_timestamp", updatable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Instant createTimestamp;

    @Volatile
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String createdBy;//

    @Volatile
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "update_timestamp")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Instant updateTimestamp;

    @Volatile
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private String updatedBy;//

    @Column(name = "effective_start_date")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Builder.Default
    private Instant effectiveStartDate = Instant.now();

    @Volatile
    @Column(name = "effective_end_date")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Builder.Default
    private Instant effectiveEndDate = DateTimeUtils.UNLIMITED_LOCAL_INSTANT;

    @Volatile
    @Column(name = "effective_sales_end_date")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Builder.Default
    private Instant effectiveSalesEndDate = Instant.now();

    @Column(name = "migration_id")
    private String migrationId;//

    @Deprecated
    @Column(name = "interlineability")
    private Boolean interlineability;

    @Column(name = "interline_indicator")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private InterlineIndicatorOption interlineIndicator;

    @Builder.Default
    @Column(name = "fare_update_in_progress")
    private Boolean fareUpdateInProgress = false;

    @Transient
    public boolean isOneWay() {
        return journeys != null && journeys.isOpenWayJourney();
    }

    @Transient
    public boolean isReturn() {
        return journeys != null && journeys.isReturnJourney();
    }

    public void setNewKeys(LongSupplier supplier) {
        if (this.getId() == 0) {
            this.setId(supplier.getAsLong());
        }
        this.setRuleKey(supplier.getAsLong());
    }

    public void addMigrationId(String carrierFareRuleId) {
        if (migrationId == null) {
            migrationId = carrierFareRuleId;
        } else {
            migrationId = migrationId + "," + carrierFareRuleId;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAdhoc() {
        return StringUtils.isBlank(code);
    }
}

In here there are some string values and db type is varchar.
After migrating spring boot 3 and hibernate 6, when those string values saving those are converted in to hexadecimal values as varbinary due to this limited charactor violation is happening. below is the postgres log
2024-05-06 09:45:59.495 ERROR 33429 --- [ault-executor-0] c.a.p.f.i.ErrorHandlerInterceptor        : could not execute statement [ERROR: value too long for type character varying(2)
  Where: unnamed portal with parameters: 
  
  
  
  
  $1 = 'TRUE', 
  $2 = 'TRUE', 
  $3 = 'TRUE', 
  $4 = 'TRUE', 
  $5 = 'TRUE', 
  $6 = 'TRUE', 
  $7 = 'TRUE', 
  $8 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c74726565740000', 
  $9 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c74726565740000', 
  $10 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c7472656574000841524f534d41444c', 
  $11 = '2024-05-06 04:15:59.474945+00', 
  $12 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c7472656570', 
  $13 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c74726565740003495252', 
  $14 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c74726565740000', 
  $15 = '3999-12-31 18:30:00+00', 
  $16 = '2024-05-06 04:15:59.255437+00', 
  $17 = '2024-05-07 00:00:00+00', 
  $18 = 'FALSE', 
  $19 = 'TRUE', 
  $20 = 'FALSE', 
  $21 = '4', 
  $22 = 'NON_INTERLIENABLE', 
  $23 = 'FALSE', 
  $24 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c7472656570', 
  $25 = '1', 
  $26 = '1', 
  $27 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c7472656574000646523a203238', 
  $28 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c747265657400024e54', 
  $29 = '2024-05-06 04:15:59.475003+00', 
  $30 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c7472656570', 
  $31 = '\xaced00057372001c6f72672e706f737467726573716c2e7574696c2e50476f626a6563744bf895caac6f64440200024c0004747970657400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b4c000576616c756571007e000178707400056c74726565740003312e30', 
  $32 = '28'] 
  
  
  
  [insert into fare_rules (
  active,
  allowed_adult_refund,
  allowed_child_refund,
  allowed_infant_refund,
  allowed_adult,
  allowed_child,
  allowed_infant,
  basis_code,
  booking_time,
  code,
  create_timestamp,
  created_by,
  currency_id,
  description,
  effective_end_date,
  effective_sales_end_date,
  effective_start_date,
  enable_validity_period,
  exclude_from_stopovers,
  fare_update_in_progress,
  id,
  interline_indicator,
  interlineability,
  migration_id,
  min_pax_count,
  pax_category_id,
  segment_name,
  type,
  update_timestamp,
  updated_by,
  version,
  rule_key
  
  
  ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)];

How to prevent this behaviour in springboot 3 and hibernate 6 and postres 11 as it is causing some attributes

value too long for type character varying

And also note that it is working fine in springboot 2.7 and hibernate 5

afaik that should just remain a string, what did you do to upgrade/ Are you managing dependencies yourself? Are you setting the dialect properly? Which database are you using? On a different note, using @ToString and @EqualsAndHashCode with entities is a bad idea (the same as @Data). For JPA you probably only want to us the ruleKey for hashCode and equals not the rest (for proper state transitioning).

I am using postres 11 and using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect dialect, and as mentioned in the post this was working fine with springboot 2.7 and hibernate 5

Frankly I don't really care if it worked before, doesn't mean it was correct back then. Hibernate 6 became more strict on what to accept with "wrong" configuration etc. so please add some code and configuration to what you are doing.

@shanG Can you try to add columnDefinition = "varchar" to all of your String fields? Like this for example: @Column(name = "code", columnDefinition="varchar")

@M. Deinum could you please explain why it should be bad to use ´@EqualsAndHashCode´ with an entity? If you exclude the id field by annotating it correctly there should be no problem with that. Also ruleKey is the only column you would never want to include, since that leads to not being able to use equals and hashCode before persisting the entity. Usually you should exclude the PrimaryKey and ensure uniqueness differently

No you shouldn't you should include the primary key and exclude everything else for JPA to work. The object identity (hashcode) and equality (equals) shouldn't change during the lifecycle (state transitions) of the entity. If you include all the fields those change and JPA can get confused.

@Vlad Mihalcea Can you please guide on this
